# End of line evaluation within PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, csv, end-of-line

I use a form which purpose is to generate a customized .csv file. Among other things, the user can specify the end of line character.

To do so, he simply enters it in a text area. I have a problem with the backslashed characters, and in particular "\n".

If I don't check the string, the "\n" entered by the user isn't evaluated. It is added to the .csv file as a string, and the outputed CSV has only one line with all the values...: `value1\nvalue2\n` instead of :

```
value 1
value 2
...
```

So far, I've found a way to deal with it, making the following test :

```
if ($var == '\n') {
$var = "\n";
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Add checkboxes/radio with possible options.

Comment: why are you giving this as an option? "\n" is a very standard way of ending datalines in csv files

Comment: the problem will be the same, what I want to know is how to force the evaluation of the string as an end-of-file character

Comment: I could let this "\n" option forced by default, but now I'm curious of what happened. I found a way to avoid the error, I just want to know why it happens in this case...

Comment: give this a quick read and then look at how you read the csv file and how you read the input from the user: [PHP Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: I currently use 

`if (isset($_GET['var'])) {
 $var = $_GET['var'];
}`

I also tried with double quotes